# How does conscious rational internal thought gets initiated - what gives rise to it on any given day?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, rationality

I'm reading a book called "The power of now" by Ekhart Tolle, and in that book he suggests that internal dialogue/monologue/planning/judging can be first observed, then disidentified with and eventually stopped consciously.

This makes me ask - **Does modern cognitive science know what exactly causes the mind to switch into a rational, linear and verbal thought pattern?**

Examples of such thought would be: "I'm thinking right now about asking a question on stack overflow, I should word this question in such a way that it is easily understood." Another example would be repeating a shopping list: "Milk, bread, eggs, ice cream, etc, etc etc......"

I'm looking for an answer on which parts of the brain and which neurotransmitter systems are involved in initiation and sustained focus on rational, linear, verbal thought.