# How do ideas come to our minds?

Tags: creativity, brain

how does a new or creative idea come to mind ? or else how does an idea that leads you to solve a problem you have been working on for days suddenly come up ? you just feel like it lightened up in your mind, 
Is there an area in the brain responsible for this, can this be explained by an activation of neurons in that area ?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/how-do-i-choose-what-i-think, https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-does-conscious-rational-internal-thought-gets-initiated-what-gives-rise-to, https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-is-it-that-taking-a-break-from-a-problem-sometimes-allows-you-to-figure-out

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg: thanks that was really helpful